# GNOME 3.14 and Google Drive integration

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, google-drive

In Gnome 3.14 On Line Account Settings, if I add a Google account, under "use this account for" I can switch Documents on/off.
This in my understanding should synchronize my documents with my Google Drive. So I would expect to see some folder like "Google Drive" on Nautilus showing my Google Drive contents. But I can't see anything like that.
Is my understanding wrong or do I need any extra packages for that?
I'm on Arc Linix.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'documents' app in gnome is supposed to sync with online resources (google docs, ownCloud, oneDrive). I don't have 3.14, but in 3.10 the application is seriously slow and sucktastic. It's totally useless.

https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-documents/stable/

Comment: Thank'you! I di not install it in my arch box. I'm going to test it now on GS 3.16